# ¿como agrego una propiedad a un objeto dentro de un estado de react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

El problema es que tengo campos dinámicos, los cuales cuando los modifico quiero que se modifique una URL de consulta a una API. Para solucionar esto pensé en utilizar un estado para guardar un array con los parámetros y valores para después concatenarlos.

Lo que pasa es que cada vez que modifico un campo el otro se borra y lo que quiero hacer es agregarle una propiedad al objeto sin perder los datos existentes.

```js
const[urlParams,setUrlParams]= useState()

const writeParamUrl =(e)=>{
        const param = e.target.value
        const it = e.target.name.substring(4,5)//esto es para sacar el id del campo
        const parametros= {}
        parametros[it]={item:param}
            
        setUrlParams({...urlParams,...parametros})
    }


    const writeValueUrl =(e)=>{
        const value = e.target.value
        const it = e.target.name.substring(4,5)
        const valores= {}
        valores[it]={valor:value}
            
        setUrlParams({...urlParams,...valores})
    }
  
return(
  <input type="text" {...register(`all.${index}.item`)} className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>writeParamUrl(e)} placeholder="Item" />
            <input type="text" {...register(`all.${index}.value`)}className="form-control" onChange={(e)=>writeValueUrl(e)}  placeholder="Value" />
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Que estructura esperas almacenar en urlParams?

Comment: Intenta hacer un paso intermedio. En vez de copiar el valor del estado y la variable dentro del setState, crea una nueva variable por ejemplo `let newValue = {...urlParams,...valores}`, y esa variable se la pasas al setState `setUrlParams(newValue)`.

Comment: lo que te sucede es que cuando quieres setear `{valor: value}` te borra el `{item: value}`?

Comment: lo solucione asii graciass